# How to Perform Spark Streaming with Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: python, google-sheets, spark-streaming, read-write, real-time-data

I want to build one application which will be running locally supporting real time data processing, and need to built using python.

The input that needs to be provided in real time, and which is in the form of google spreadsheets (Multiple users are providing there data at a time).

Also, needs to write real time output of the code back to spreadsheets in it's adjacent column.

Please help me for the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [spark-google-spreadsheets](https://github.com/potix2/spark-google-spreadsheets) library to read and write to Google Sheets from Spark, [as described here](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/read-google-sheets-dataframe/).

Here's an example of how you can read data from a Google Sheet into a DataFrame:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.
    format("com.github.potix2.spark.google.spreadsheets").
    load("<spreadsheetId>/worksheet1")
```

Incremental updates will be tough.  You might want to just try doing full refreshes.